# NVRM: API mismatch despite having the same version on client and kernel

Tags: gpu, driver, nvidia, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed **nvidia driver 440.64**.

After reboot, I get a black screen instead of the login screen. I pressed CTRL+ALT+F3 to console login and typed `sudo prime-select intel`. The login screen appears and I can login.

After login, I type `nvidia-smi` :

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

I do the following:

```
prime-select query
```

Output:

```
intel
```

Then

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

Output:

```
Info: selecting the nvidia profile
```

Then

```
nvidia-smi
```

Output:

```
Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch
```

Then

```
dmesg
```

Output:

```
...
[   68.122795] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 440.64.00, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 440.64.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
...
```

If I reboot, I run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install the nvidia-driver-440 from the [nvidia deb repo](https://developer.download.nvidia.cn/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/) will fix it.

The nvidia driver and client library should come from the same repository or the version most likely mismatch.